# Converting base32 to a decimal number

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, decimal, base32

Is there anybody who can help me converting base32 values to decimal numbers?
I have a sql statement which returns me a list of base32 values. For example the return of the select looks like this:

5

8

H

13r

Now I need to figure out which of these values is the highest (in this case 13r). Therefore I would need a function to convert these base32 values to decimal numbers in order to sort them.
Does anybody have such a function or does anybody have a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be little bit tricky.

You can create a `function` which will separate each character/digit from the original base32 number and multiply it with 32^(position in base32 number) to get decimal equivalent number and use that `function` in your query.

> ```
> create function convert32todecimal(p_num in varchar2)
> return number 
> as
> lv_outnum number;
> begin
> select sum(val) into lv_outnum from
> (
>   select power(32,pos) * case when d between '0' and '9' 
>                 then to_number(d)
>                 else 10 + ascii(d) - ascii('A')
>            end as val
>     from (
>           select upper(substr(p_num,length(p_num)+1-level,1)) d,
>                  level - 1 as pos
>             from dual
>             connect by level <= length(p_num)
>          )
> );
> return lv_outnum;
> end;
> /
> ```

Now, use this function in your query as following:

> ```
> with your_data(num) as (
> select '5' from dual union all
> select '8' from dual union all
> select 'H' from dual union all
> select '13r' from dual
> )
> select num, convert32todecimal(num)
> from your_data
> order by 2 desc;
> ```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=34b0bcecc5ddc1ba9756a80f49860d90)

Cheers!!